# What is EngineServer.exe and should I kill it?

Tags: process, task-manager, mcafee

I've got this process running on my work computer and it's starting to take up quite a bit of memory. I know it belongs to McAffee but, is it possible to disable it directly? killing it from the Task Manager doesn't work.

Thanks

Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://community.mcafee.com/showthread.php?t=225253) on the McAfee forums (kinda old) regarding a possible memory leak with that binary.  There's a suggestion of upgrading near the bottom.